# vb.net Running MySQL queries fast

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select, listbox

I have two listboxes in my windows form where the first one contains a bunch of IDs and when an ID is selected, all its properties from the MySQL database are displayed using the second listbox.

My code:

```
Private Sub lstUsersKey_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstUsersKey.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (lstUsersKey.SelectedIndex.ToString IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim UserID As Integer = CInt(lstUsersKey.SelectedItem.ToString)

        lstUsersValue.Items.Clear()

        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("User ID: " & UserID)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Forename: " & frmLogin.User.GetForename)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Surname: " & frmLogin.User.GetSurname)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Admin: " & frmLogin.User.IsAdmin)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Username: " & frmLogin.User.GetUsername)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Password: -") '& frmLogin.User.GetPassword
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Phone Number: " & frmLogin.User.GetPhoneNumber)
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Address: " & frmLogin.User.GetAddress())
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Postcode: " & frmLogin.User.GetPostcode())
        lstUsersValue.Items.Add("Email Address: " & frmLogin.User.GetUserEmailAddress)
    End If
End Sub
```

A function from my User class looks something like this but with different parameters:

```
Function GetPostcode()
    Return frmLogin.MySQL.SelectQuery("Postcode", "tbluser", "Username", "@username", Me.Username)
End Function
```

My MySQL class contains this function:

```
Function SelectQuery(ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal tblName As String, ByVal ConditionColumn As String, ByVal ConditionCheckOperator As String, ByVal ConditionCheckValue As String)
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT " & ColumnName & " " & "FROM " & tblName & " " & "WHERE " & ConditionColumn & "=" & ConditionCheckOperator
    Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection(frmLogin.MySQL.ConnectionDetails)
    Dim Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Connection)
    Connection.Open()
    Dim Result As Object
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConditionCheckOperator, ConditionCheckValue)
    Result = Command.ExecuteScalar
    Command.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()
    If Result IsNot Nothing Then
        Return Result.ToString
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

The problem is no data is being loaded from my database and I'm not sure how to fix it and whether there is an easier way to run a lot of queries without having to make a new connection every time I want to run a query.

Comment: a) you are *supposed* to create a new connection each time b) use SQL parameters instead gluing bits of string together c) dont store passwords in plaintext d) if you know you are going to show the data use a `DataTable` and a `DataView` to change what shows e) that function doesnt do much but return the number of matching rows - something else must get the actual data (again)  f) Turn on `Option Strict`.  It sounds like 'e' is your problem - you arent doing anything with the data

Comment: `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)` isnt doing what you think either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by changing how my SelectQuery Function works. I found an efficient way to run queries on stackoverflow, so I copied the code and adapted it.

```
Function SelectQuery(ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal tblName As String, ByVal ConditionColumn As String, ByVal Operator1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Object)
        Dim Query As String = "SELECT " & ColumnName & " " & "FROM " & tblName & " " & "WHERE " & ConditionColumn & "=" & Operator1
        Dim Result As String = ""

        Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionDetails)
            Using Comm As New MySqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = Conn
                    .CommandText = Query
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue(Operator1, Value1)
                End With
                Try
                    Conn.Open()
                    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
                    While Reader.Read() OrElse (Reader.NextResult And Reader.Read)
                        Result += Reader.GetString(0)
                    End While
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return "Error"
                    MsgBox("select error: " & ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        Return Result

    End Function
```